# Best way to do sprites in SCSS?

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass

I trying to make my life easier with sass, but it seems that I'm toooo noob ...

I want simplify the way I use bullets..... that normally is like this :D

```
//The Sprite 

@mixin sprite($pos: null){
@if $pos ==  null {
    background:url('img/assets/sprite-all.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

@else {
    background:url('img/assets/sprite-all.png') $pos no-repeat;

}
}

//The CSS // Bullets
    .bullet1-left:before,
    .bullet2-left:before,
    .bullet3-left:before,
    .bullet4-left:before,
    .bullet5-left:before,
    .bullet6-left:before,
    .bullet7-left:before,
    .bullet8-left:before,
    .bullet1-top:before,
    .bullet2-top:before,
    .bullet3-top:before,
    .bullet4-top:before,
    .bullet5-top:before,
    .bullet6-top:before,
    .bullet7-top:before,
    .bullet8-top:before{
      @include sprite;
      width:64px;
      height:65px;
      content:"";
    }

    .bullet1-left:before,
    .bullet2-left:before,
    .bullet3-left:before,
    .bullet4-left:before,
    .bullet5-left:before,
    .bullet6-left:before,
    .bullet7-left:before,
    .bullet8-left:before{
      float:left;
      padding:0 10px;
      margin:0;
      display:inline-block;
    }

    .bullet1-top:before,
    .bullet2-top:before,
    .bullet3-top:before,
    .bullet4-top:before,
    .bullet5-top:before,
    .bullet6-top:before,
    .bullet7-top:before,
    .bullet8-top:before{
      display:block;
      padding:10px 0;
      margin: 0 auto;  
    }

    .bullet1-left:before{}
    .bullet2-left:before{}
    .bullet3-left:before{}
    .bullet4-left:before{}
    .bullet5-left:before{}
    .bullet6-left:before{}
    .bullet7-left:before{}
    .bullet8-left:before{}

    .bullet1-top:before{}
    .bullet2-top:before{}
    .bullet3-top:before{}
    .bullet4-top:before{}
    .bullet5-top:before{}
    .bullet6-top:before{}
    .bullet7-top:before{}
    .bullet8-top:before{}
```

What's the best way to simplify all this???, can somebody give me a hand on this please

Answer (score 0):

try `[class^="bullet"][class$="-top"]:before {}`. I'm not exactly sure how to do multiple selectors on same html tag, but worth a shot. more on selectors [here](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). If that doesn't work, try putting `[class^="bullet"]>[class$="-top"]:before'.

**EDIT:** I did a basic test, and what I originally said works same as commented out part in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyomu/L7HG6/1/embedded/result/).

Comment: Wow , that’s a super interesting approach , I really didn't know that, that exist...hehe....but the problem come , when I need a lot of different bullets in a sprite.. http://jsfiddle.net/L7HG6/4/

Comment: I think I may have missed the point of what you needed then. My idea was to get rid of all those commas :). What should it be doing instead? Also, I didn't know sass existed until yesterday =p

Comment: either way, that was a great solution for another day, thanks very much

Comment: So, was that sorta what you needed, or did you need something else? Or did my idea partially work but not the way you wanted?